# How does a FinFET reduce subthreshold swing comparing to a regular MOSFET?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, solid-state-devices, finfet

I get that a lower subthreshold swing means there is a smaller current when the transistor is off and that's one of the reasons that finFET is preffered to MOSFET. But I don't understand how it does that. 
I've been googling it and all I find is complicated advanced papers on improve finFETs and things like that. 
Can you explain this or refer me to a place I can read about it in simple words?

Comment: I don't think I've heard of a FinFET until I read this question. Quite an interesting topology. However, I don't think you tried hard enough to research this topic. I copied and pasted your question (because frankly, I have no idea what this thing is) and I found an answer on [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_does_FinFET_reduce_subthreshold_current). Simple words are not for us to decide since we have no knowledge of your experience with such topics.

Comment: Provide I_V drain curves for both FINFETS and regular FETs.